# Regex have a mandatory character in string

Tags: regex

I need to create a Regex for data validation for a PO.
PO should start with `PO` and have from 8 to 12 characters and mandatory contain a letter like **T** for example. Should match if is like this:

```
PO123T5678
PO1T34567T12
PO12345678912T
```

I wrote something like this but it's not working.

```
\^PO([a-zA-Z0-9]{6,11})(T+)(T?)$\
```

Comment: Maybe `^PO[a-zA-Z0-9]{6,11}T?$`? Can `T` appear in the middle?

Comment: Or perhaps using a positive lookahead `^PO(?=.{6,10}$)[a-zA-Z0-9]*T[a-zA-Z0-9]*$`

Comment: Please explain the requirements in more detail. Can there be more than one `T`s? Any other letters? When saying "it's not working" always say what exactly is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Try: `PO(?=[1-9]*T)[1-9T]{8,12}`
The first bit will ensure that the string starts with `PO` and is followed by some number of integers and `T`. Then, the characters in the next brackets will be required at 8-12 times.

Comment: That would also match `PO12345678` which doesn't contain a mandatory letter.

Comment: Updated now that I understand the requirements further. maybe this will help.

Comment: I can't say I understand OP's needs, but since that matches all 3 samples that might very well be it.

Answer (score 0):

This: `^PO(?=[0-9]*?T)[0-9T]{8,12}$` seems to do the job: See [DEMO](https://regexr.com/48j8n).
It uses a positive lookahead to ensure the `T` and then checks the rest.

Comment: You could reduce redundancy a lot by starting the lookahead after having matched `PO` and stopping it once you've reached the `T` (since that's what you can't check without a lookahead). No need to validate the rest twice.

Comment: @Aaron True, thanks. I tend to be overly careful with matching stuff and not care too much about performance since i mostly use regex in single-use scenarios.

Comment: You're welcome! I find avoiding redundancy not only helps regarding performance (which you shouldn't expect to be great with regex anyway) but also maintainability. Not that it matters either in single-use cases!

Answer (score 0):

I'd use a positive lookahead, assuming your regex flavour supports it:

```
^PO(?=.*T)([a-zA-Z0-9]{6,10})$
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/c18YbE/1)

Comment: Looking at the provided samples, it seems that the 8-12 characters restrinction is on the sequence that follows `PO` rather than on the whole string (the 3rd sample is 14 chars long).

Comment: @Aaron:This point is not really clear. I assumed the whole string is 8 to 12. Waiting for clarification from OP.